# Apply color to a specific word in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I want to apply color to a specific word in a range. for example in the range below I want to add color to word "Henry" (Please pay attention that some cells have more than one "Henry". I want to add color to all "Henry" in the range.

```
         A
1  Henry is Henry
2  Lean and REyhan came
3  Fendo Henry came 
4  dce
5  Henry and Henry uu Henry
```

My code not only apply color to Henry but apply color to the first five character of every cell. I don't know why.

```
Sub search()

  Set m_wsSheet1 = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A5")

  searchWord = "Henry"

  For Each celld In m_wsSheet1
    kkk = 1
    Do
      kkk = InStr(kkk, celld, searchWord )
      mmm = kkk
      celld.Characters(kkk, Len(searchWord)).Font.Color = RGB(221, 21, 221)
      kkk = kkk + Len(searchWord )
    Loop While mmm > 0
  Next

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the variable `aaa` in your sub supposed to be? It seems to be the same as `searchword`? You also have two different `m_wsSheet` in your code, one of which isn't defined.

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you say it does. Your variable names are all mixed up. Please write `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and declare all of your variables using `Dim`. This will help you find your own mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done a version using your variable names. You were halfway there. Just didn't need the aaa or mmm variable, your second sheet name was incorrect and exit criteria for the loop didn't work.

In future make sure your indentation is correct and variables are declared. Also try and come up with better variable names.

```
Sub search()

'add in declarations
Dim m_wsSheet1 As Range
Dim celld As Range
Dim kkk As Integer
Dim searchWord As String
Dim blnEndSearch As Boolean


Set m_wsSheet1 = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A5")

searchWord = "Henry"

For Each celld In m_wsSheet1 'changed to same range as above

    kkk = 1 'starting search position

    Do
        'finds starting position of search word
        kkk = InStr(kkk, celld.Value, searchWord) 'changed aaa to searchWord

        'if we've found a match
        If kkk <> 0 Then
            'colours found word
            celld.Characters(kkk, Len(searchWord)).Font.Color = RGB(221, 21, 221)

            'start at end of last position
            kkk = kkk + Len(searchWord)
        End If

    Loop While kkk <> 0

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for making it work, might I suggest renaming of variables? This makes it a lot more easier to know what variable does what, with the current setup `kkk`, `celld` are a bit confusing. Good work though. Also you could pass the **word** to the Sub, than hardcoding.